# Is there a ZoomIn and ZoomOut method Google Maps V3

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I created a custom zoom control and want to zoom in and zoom out onclick...can I access the method that is default to zoomIn and zoomOut in Google v3 API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such function. You just call `map.setZoom()`:

```
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1); // zoom in
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1); // zoom out
```